# (OAuthException - #200) (#200) The target user has not authorized this action

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created a facebook app and have appid and secretkey. Also I created a appaccess token using graphapi for my app. (I selected my app in the drop down list and created an access token with extended permission). Then I created a test user for my app. This means the test user has authorzied my app. Since Feb 2013 FB has removed the graph api feature which posts messages in friend's wall, I am trying to  post the messages using my app. Like games apps posting the scores in users' wall. I want to post the messages to my friend's wall. So in my app, I have a button click event which has the following code.

```
var accessToken = "xxxxxxCAACbZCbvLNIUBAEHXHZAR7jlVXcGNtnLpTOWuew9V2gbQMWgnIInCX8fZ";
            FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

            dynamic me = client.Get("me");

            client.Post("/myfriend'sid10000636/feed", new { message = "Hi hello My Message" });
```

This throws an exception : (OAuthException - #200) (#200) The target user has not authorized this action

Comment: You shouldn't share app secrets or app access tokens on SO

Comment: It is partial token. The real token has 2 lines.

Comment: Has your test user, who i assume is the target of the post, authorised your app with the publish_stream or publish_actions permission?

Comment: Both permissions + manage_pages as well.